# React property map issue

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, render

I'm trying to do example of **React Website** and I got this:

```
function renderSuperheroesTable(props) {
    return (
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Powers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {props.superheros.map(superhero =>
                    <tr key={superhero.name}>
                        <td>{superhero.name}</td>
                        <td>{superhero.powers}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

While Im running I got below message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
**renderSuperheroesTable**
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can we have your parent component ?

Comment: `props.superheros` is undefined. try first with `{props.superheros && props.superheros.map(superhero =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the length of array first, then iterate over it using map:

```
function renderSuperheroesTable({ superheroes }) {
    
    
    return (
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Powers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {superheros.length > 0 && superheros.map(superhero =>
                    <tr key={superhero.name}>
                        <td>{superhero.name}</td>
                        <td>{superhero.powers}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the first time `props.superheros` prop value maybe is undefined and `undefined` has not the `map` property to iterate, So you have to check its type and it was not an array, you should assign an array to the `map` property.

Try to use this way:

```js
{(Array.isArray(props.superheros) ? props.superheros : []).map(superhero =>
   <tr key={superhero.name}>
      <td>{superhero.name}</td>
      <td>{superhero.powers}</td>
   </tr>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you got to use return when you map in render and please check if the props.superheros is an array and

```
{props.superheros?props.superheros.map((element)=>{
  //your code 
 })
 :null  //if undefined it prints nul
 }
```